# What is the proper way for binding data to cascade dropdown / autocomplete lists in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I use `mat-autocomplete` in several places in my project and fille them as shwon below on form loading:

```
countries: CountryDto[] = [];
cities: CityDto[] = [];


getCountries() {
  this.demoService.getCountries().subscribe((list: CountryDto) => {
    this.countries = list;
  });
}

getCities(countryId) {
  this.demoService.getCities(countryId).subscribe((list: CityDto) => {
    this.cities= list;
  });
}
```

However, when I tried to use a second list as cascade, I cannot make the second one to fill according to the first selection. Actually I pass the countryId and then retrieve the city list without any problem. But, I cannot refresh the list of cities. I also tried to use `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and `ngZone.run()`, but it does not make any sense. I am not sure if the problem is related to `subscribe` section, and for this reason I am too confused after trying lots of different tgings to fix the problem. So, first I need to start with a proper approach that is suitable for **cascade** binding. How can apply a proper way?

Comment: please share template and ts code..entire code block

Comment: @NileshPatel Thanks for help, but it is too comlicated and it is better to omit unncessaey parts to omit. What do you need to examine the problem? I will tryt to give more detailed info. Regards.

Comment: you have not share necessary part either..

Comment: Sorry, but which part do you need? html part? On the other hand, I am using a custom reusable mat-autocomplete. Another point that may causing the problem is that I may need to use Observable for the lists. Is that true?

Comment: If you give a proper way example I can try to integrate that approach to fix the problem.

Comment: please checkout [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdow-city-state)

Comment: Thnaks a lot, I am examinig that approach. Do I have to use ngModel? Is there any proper solution without using it?

Answer (score 2):

Simplifly the Daniel's idea, you can defined a observable like

```
cities$=this.citiesForm.get('state').valueChange.pipe(
  switchMap(countryId=>this.demoService.getCities(countryId),
  tap(_=>this.citiesForm.get('city').setValue(null)
)
```

And use

```
<options *ngFor="let s of cities$ | async">
```

Usig ngModel is equal

```
<select [ngModel]="state" (ngModelChange)="stateChange($event)" >
 ...
</select>


stateChange(countryId)
{
  this.state=state;
  this.cities$=this.demoService.getCities(countryId).pipe(
      tap(_=>this.city=null
  )
}
```

See that the idea is return an observable and use pipe async in the .html. The operator "tap" make that, when you subscribe -remember that the pipe async is a way to subscribe- the city becomes null

Comment: Thnaks a lot for you helps, voted up. I think I have another problem that causes error for this issue. I use a custom autocomplete control in this form and that's why I have difficulties to update its value after loading. So, how can I set a custom control input value later?  I have `@Input() options: any[];` as input and should I use some input with setter like `@Input() set options(data: any)` ? How can I integrate it to this custom autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing imperative and reactive programming by fetching the data and then assigning the parsed response to a variable. Angular can handle observable values just fine without ever having to `subscribe` to anything, by instead using the `async` pipe.

There's nothing wrong with using `[(ngModel)]` to bind values and to handle changes, but as a rule of thumb, when using `Observables` to populate the form based on selected values, I like to use only reactive programming with reactive forms instead of model-bindings.

A simple reactive form for you in this case could look something like

```
  citiesForm = new FormGroup({
    state: new FormControl(),
    city: new FormControl()
  });
```

with the corresponding HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="citiesForm">
    <select formControlName="state" >
    .....
```

This makes it very easy to use the `valueChanges` event on either the `FormGroup` or it's individual `FormControl`s.

To demonstrate with a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdow-city-state-tknzwv?file=src/app/app.component.ts), we can replace everything with observable values and a reactive form.

First, we declare our observables that will populate the form.

```
  states$: Observable<Array<any>>;
  cities$: Observable<Array<any>>;
```

We initiliaze the observables in the `ngOnInit` function (note the `valueChanges`).

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.states$ = of(this.states);

    this.cities$ = combineLatest(
      this.citiesForm.get("state").valueChanges, // Will trigger when state changes
      of(this.cities)
    ).pipe(
      map(([selectedState, cities]) =>
        cities.filter(c => c.state === +selectedState) //SelectedState is a string
      )
    );
  }
```

and lastly bind everything to our form (note the `async` pipe and the form bindings to our reactive form)

```
<select formControlName="state" >
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option *ngFor="let s of states$ | async" [value]="s.id">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```

---

Since you mentioned manual triggering of change detection using `ChangeDetectorRef` in your question, notice that my proposed answer uses the `OnPush` change detection strategy, and there's no need to think about change detection since the `async` pipe will know that emission of new values in the observables will affect the template and render it properly.

Comment: you can use switchMap also instead of CombineLatests

Comment: Thnaks a lot for you helps, voted up. I think I have another problem that causes error for this issue. I use a custom autocomplete control in this form and that's why I have difficulties to update its value after loading. So, how can I set a custom control input value later?  I have `@Input() options: any[];` as input and should I use some input with setter like `@Input() set options(data: any)` ? How can I integrate it to this custom autocomplete?

Comment: You should look into implementing your own `ControlValueAccessor` for that case, and if you have problems create a new more specific question for that!