# What is advantages of Intercept input property changes with a setter?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, components

I have used some of the approaches to pass data between parent-child or sibling components e.g. @Input, EventEmitter, BehaviorSubject. On the other hand, there is also another approach [Intercept input property changes with a setter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), but I do not catch the exact advantage of using that approach over @Input or EventEmitter. So, could you explain what is the idea of using it instead of other approach(es)?

Comment: From the docs  - "The setter of the name input property in the child NameChildComponent trims the whitespace from a name and replaces an empty value with default text.". They're adding logic which is triggered when the incoming value is set, to transform the value or do other things. With a variable you just accept the incoming value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I read it, but a need a logical comparison between it and just using `@Input` feature.

Comment: You use a setter in an Input when a change of the `@Input` from your parent need "create" a series of actions, imagine, e.g. make a complex calculate or call an API. You can not do it in ngOnInit. If you only need show the variable in .html of the children you don't use the setter

Comment: @Eliseo Do you mean that if I need to make some update regarding to the input after `ngOninit` then it is better to use this approach rather than just using @Input feature? I think with this approach, I can update the input values from parent and I can update that values in the child whenever I fire setter? Is that all true?

Comment: Setters are just useful in this case if you need to transform the data or hook into a given update of one input. You can basically use this instead of ngOnChanges for example. One common use case for me is to turn the value into an observable. I use the setter to push the value passed from the parent into a private subject. This is just one example

Comment: @maxime1992 Good example, could you post it as answer? ACtually I want to pass the selected value of a dropdownlist from child to parent and then after filling the other dropdownlist pass the options (data) from parent to child. I think for this scenario your example would be very useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Setters are just useful in this case if you need to transform the data or hook into a given update of one input.

You can basically use this instead of the `ngOnChanges` hook for example.

One common use case for me is to turn the value into an Observable. I wish there was a native way within Angular to access an input as an observable (see [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5689#issuecomment-735428857)). So in the meantime, I use the setter to push the value passed from the parent into a private subject.

This is just one example, you can do any kind of transformation really

Comment: Many thanks for your helps and good explanations. I have  alook at that issue and it is too long and some kind of sifferent solutions. Which solution do you refer and suggest to follow in that page?

Comment: On the other hand, my child component is a custom sutocomplete based on mat-autocomplete and I want to update its value based on its parent that is also the same component like State  and City autocomplete lists. I think this approach is suitable for me but I am not sure if I am on the right track. I am passing the selected id of the parent from these custom autocomplete component to the form component. ANd then according to this value, I retrieve child autocomplete list values and then pass it to the custom component (child).

Comment: >>> Then I am trying to update the options of the child component with this value. Is that correct approach? Or would you suggest sometjing different?

Answer (score 1):

Fredrick, take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195468/what-is-the-proper-way-for-binding-data-to-cascade-dropdown-autocomplete-lists/65197792#65197792)
I's only an example, If your "children" is an autocomplete of the "cities", your children can be like

```
@Input() control:FormControl
@Input()set state(value)
{
    this.cities$=this.service.getCities(value)
}
```

See that control is a "normal" `@Input`, and state is a setter that create an observable. See that even in "children" there are nothing called "state"

```
<input [formControl]="control">
<div *ngFor="let city of cities$|async" 
         (click)="control.setValue(city.id)">
     {{city.name}}
</div>
```

And you parent

```
 <form [formGroup]="form>
     <input formControlName="state">
     <app-children [control]="form.get('city')">
                   [state]="from.get('state').value">
     </app-children>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to apply and ask if I have a question.

Comment: For now, voted up of curse ;)

Comment: ::glups:: in input is `set state(value)`, not `set state(state)`, just corrected